# Rails permit params not working for multiple checkboxes and multi select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

Creating new entry for Associate model have `book_id` and `tag_id`. My requirement is to have a list of checkboxes of books and multi-select for tags, which I have done like that

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:book_id, books_hash, :last, :first) do |b| %>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <%= b.check_box class: 'form-check-input' %>
      <%= b.label class: 'form-check-label' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
   <%= form.label :tag_id %>
   <%= form.select :tag_id, options_for_select(Tag.pluck(:title,:id)), {}, {:multiple => true, :class => "chzn-select" } %>
</div>
```

Permit params are like this

```
params.require(:book_tag).permit(book_id: [], tag_id: [])
```

But issue is that when I save the record it gives an error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Book must exist, Tag must exist):

Processing by BookTagsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "book_tag"=>{"book_id"=>["5"], "tag_id"=>["2", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Create Book tag"}
```

I can't understand what exactly i am missing.

Comment: can you upload an image of the server logs ? what happens when you click submit and the model as well if you have write anything on  it, also in order to get multi values the params should be like this {:book_id =>[]}

Comment: @kostasew updated the question and added those logs

Comment: i think the issue is here "book_id"=>["", "5"]"   the First value is empty string,  do  you want the first value to be empty ? if not do you have anything on your model that do now allow to pass empty values ? any validates ?

Comment: No I don't want empty string .... can't understand how its getting

Comment: @kostasew empty string issue is fixed...but same error

Comment: Maybe in your book_tag model "accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_id"